# Do non-inertial effects impact velocity, or just acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

Suppose you measure motion in a non-inertial frame and get fictitious acceleration terms from centrifugal and Coriolis forces. Will these terms produce fictitious velocity terms?

Dumb question, and I should know this, but right now I'm struggling to answer this simple question.

Answer (score 2):

Newton's Second law as a differential equation doesn't say anything about velocity, you need initial conditions for that. Lets imagine you have an expression for the force observed while in a non inertial frame accelerating at $\vec{a}_{frame}$,

$$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}_{} - m\vec{a}_{frame}$$

Now we can solve for the actual $\vec{a}$, and we are done as far in considering the frame. To now solve for the E.O.M. and correspondingly the velocity, you need to know initial conditions, which are provided by taking the difference between your frame and what you are observing at the time of observing I.C.

$$\vec{x}_{object}(0)=\vec{x}_{observed}(0)$$
$$\vec{v}_{object}(0)=\vec{v}_{observed}(0)-\vec{v}_{frame}(0)$$

So if you are accelerating at $1 \frac{m}{s^2}$, your observing free fall, you can definitely find the acceleration of the object in free fall regardless of how fast you are going, but when you try to calculate the objects velocity/position it matters how fast you were going(i.e. were you speeding up from rest or $100 \frac{m}{s}$)

Answer (score 0):

The Coriolis theorem is applied to obtain the equations of motion of particles when using a non-inertial reference frame. In order to do so, it is first applied to the kinematics and then the dynamics. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/533572/254821) explaining the physical meaning of the pseudo, non-Newtonian or non-inertial forces. In general, the answer to the essence of your question is yes. If there are non-inertial accelerations present in your observation (due to observation of motion using a non-inertial reference frame) then there will be terms related to motion of the reference frame which will appear in the expression of the velocity measured using the inertial reference frame expressed in terms of the measurement using using the inertial reference frame.